# BUY volume that raises the stock price significantly

Tags: stock-analysis

The following is the chart for Apple on 12/31/2019. As I understand from the chart, the buyers are outpacing sellers, and at 3:00 PM, the stock jumped significantly due to large buying.

My question are:

- Does the stock exchange publish the buyers and sellers volume in real time for traders to make judgement on the direction of the stock price? When I watched this chart in yahoo, it was late by a few seconds to a minute.
- Can the BUYERS VS SELLERS volume per day or week be used to speculate the direction of the stock? Is that data available from exchange website or can be available through paid service?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the stock exchange publish the buyers and sellers volume in real time for traders to make judgement on the direction of the stock price?

You can observe real time trading volume as it occurs in Time and Sales but that just shows completed trades.

> Can the BUYERS VS SELLERS volume per day or week be used to speculate the direction of the stock? Is that data available from exchange website or can be available through paid service?

Level II is the order book that shows the quotes at different market makers.  Each one displays a ranked list from each market maker showing the price and size of their  orders.

There are people who claim that they can discern the direction of the stock based on watching the order book but I've never been able to make sense out of it.  Not only do you have multiple markets makers with a shifting number or orders/size/price but you also have various kinds of hidden orders which may hide much of the volume.  For example, an Iceberg Order which breaks a large order into a number of smaller orders and only displays the 'tip of the iceberg', hiding the smaller orders below. If you can't see the true volume then how can you judge the effect that it might have?

Level II order book is a paid service.

> When I watched this chart in yahoo, it was late by a few seconds to a minute.

Yahoo has a delayed feed.  It's useless in real time.